# Equality check seems to always be true

Tags: shell-script, zsh, test

I have this function in my .zshrc:

```bsh
activated=false

function test_toggle() {
  if [ $activated=false ]; then
    echo "WAS FALSE"
    activated=true
  else
    echo "WAS TRUE"
    activated=false
  fi
}
```

I'd like the function to toggle the state of var `activated` between `false` and `true`.
But if I open a terminal and run the function I only get this:

```
$ test_toggle
WAS FALSE
$ test_toggle
WAS FALSE
$ test_toggle
WAS FALSE
```

How can I make the function use and change the variable: `activated` from parent scope correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is that `foo=bar` is assignment (same as `activated=false`), and the shell parser is assigning as a side-effect of the conditional. Always use `[[` in ZSH code over the Bourne `[`, and the `foo=bar` should instead use spaces to distinguish the test from assignment:

```
activated=false
function test_toggle() {
  if [[ $activated = false ]]; then
    echo "WAS FALSE"
    activated=true
  else
    echo "WAS TRUE"
    activated=false
  fi
}
```

Result:

```
% exec zsh
% which test_toggle
test_toggle () {
    if [[ $activated = false ]]
    then
        echo "WAS FALSE"
        activated=true 
    else
        echo "WAS TRUE"
        activated=false 
    fi
}
% echo $activated
false
% test_toggle 
WAS FALSE
% test_toggle
WAS TRUE
% test_toggle
WAS FALSE
%
```